# Chrome not properly observing onload event on script tags?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, event-handling, dom-events, onload

I am using Javascript to dynamically load in external Javascript files, and in my application I need to know when those scripts are fully loaded into memory before the rest of process can continue. I have tried the following code to monitor the `onload` event on the script tags being appened to the head:

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.onload = scriptLoaded;
newScript.src = '/path/to/file.js';
headID.appendChild(newScript);
```

<sub><sup>Source: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS</sup></sub>

This works great in FireFox (latest version Windows and OS X) however it appears that Chrome (again in both windows and OS X versions) does not observe the event properly, and the callback function is invoked prematurely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue by rewriting it with jQuery:

```
var script_tag = $('<script><\/script>');
script_tag.attr('type', 'text/javascript');
script_tag.bind('load', function(e)
{
    console.log('script loaded');
});
script_tag.attr('src', '/path/to/file.js');
$('head')[0].appendChild(script_tag[0]);
```

Not sure why this fixes it, maybe chrome just didn't like the way the script tag was being created in the first implementation using pure javascript. *shrug*

Comment: Can it be done without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You may try wrapping your function call in another function. I've had some error like you're describing and doing the following sometimes helps:

```
newScript.onload = function(){ scriptLoaded; };
```

It almost seems like Chrome is trying to evaluate `scriptLoaded` in order to assign the return value to `newScript.onload`.